# Cannot invoke hook callback with renderHook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library

I'm trying to learn about testing hooks with this trivial hook:

```js
const useStateHook = (initialValue: boolean) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
  return [value, setValue];
};
```

Here is my attempt at testing this hook:

```
describe('given basic test', () => {
  it('render hook', async () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useStateHook(false));
    const [value, setValue] = result.current;
    expect(value).toBeFalsy();
    setValue(true);
    expect(value).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

However, the `setValue` call is throwing a TypeScript error:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type 'boolean | Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>' are callable.
    Type 'false' has no call signatures.ts(2349)
```

Why can I not invoke `setValue`?

Comment: Typescript cannot infer that your return signature of your hook is `[boolean, (x: boolean) => whatever]` so it is instead `(boolean | (x: boolean) => whatever)[]`. This has nothing to do with React or hooks, and everything to do with trying to add static types to languages with heterogeneous data structures.

Comment: Thanks, this resolved it: `const useStateHook = (initialValue: boolean): [boolean, Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>] => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
  return [value, setValue];
};`